# React Native - Create and Export/Download PDF File

Tags: react-native

I'm making a project in React Native that creates a table with some data, and I need to create a pdf with that table and be able to download/export that pdf.
Currently i'm using https://github.com/christopherdro/react-native-html-to-pdf, but its downloading to cache directory, even if i change to docs.
I was searching and some people say that u need to use file manager to download a pdf.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From docs, you have to specify "Documents" directory if you want it to be saved on Documents dir of ios/android.

```
  async createPDF() {
        let options = {
            html: '<table><tr><th>Firstname</th><th>Lastname</th></tr></table>',
            fileName: 'tableTest',
            directory: 'Documents',
        };
        let file = await RNHTMLtoPDF.convert(options)
        alert(file.filePath);
  }
```

Since you are creating this table in your react native code, you don't need to download anything from anywhere. Cache directory is your phone's cache directory, so I can't understand from where you want to download the pdf.

Comment: angelos_lex Thank you for your response, but even if i use Documents it's stores on cache. So i can use https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs to store on Downloads for example?

Comment: Yes, install react-native-fs and use moveFile(file.filePath, destPath) where destPath is your decision according to [path constants here](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs#constants)

Comment: I have a pdf file. I need to store it and if the user click on the download needs to download that file. Here how can i store and download that file in react-native?